# How Assign Exponentialy increasing probablities to a random number

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution

Suppose we have a random variables with values from 1 to 1000 and we have to assign exponential increasing values to them (1 has low probability and 1000 has highest but increase in probabilities is exponential). How can i write equation for this.

Second how can i randomly pick any one of the a random variables with chances that highest probability random variable is most likely to be returned.

Let me rephrase the problem, It is same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942318/random-numbers-based-on-a-probability      only difference i explain here

considering S is random number generated to map to the numbers following exponential growth rate (exponential probability increase)  for n=1 S=1 or 2   for n=2 S=3 or 4 or 5 or 6 (S=2pow(n) ) and so. How i can solve now with arithmetic series formula ( i think it is must ) as shown in link above for exponential distribution to get n .

Comment: What do you mean by “highest probability random variable”? Do you actually mean the highest probability _value_ of the random variable you define in the first part of the question? That value _will_ be the most likely value by definition.

Comment: Let me rephrase the problem, It is same as in

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of the language of probability here. I do not think you actually want multiple random “variables”; I think you need just one random variable that has $1000$ possible values. If you talk of $1000$ random _variables_ you will be talking about something very different than the other example.

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph, I think what you asked for is not what you want. Reading the question literally, we could give you any random procedure in which $1000$ is the most likely outcome. For example $1000$ could be the result $1/2$ of the time and otherwise we choose equally likely from $1$ to $999.$ Technically that would satisfy what you asked for. But I think what you want is a procedure _in software_ that will _accurately simulate_ the random distribution you described. That is a much more specific request.

Answer (score 0):

For some $0 \le \alpha \le 1$, You can assign a probability of $\alpha$ to 1000, $\alpha^2$ to 999, ..., $\alpha^{1000}$ to 1. To make this a legitimate probability distribution (a probability mass function, strictly speaking), the probabilities must add up to 1. This implies:

$\sum_{n=1}^{1000} \alpha^n = \frac{\alpha(1-\alpha^{1000})}{1-\alpha} = 1$. You can solve numerically in a program like MATLAB or Python to calculate the value of $\alpha$ which satisfied this equation. Since the summation converges to $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$, your answer will be very close to $\alpha = 0.5$.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have an exponentially increasing probability on the integers $1$ to $n$ as long as the probability of each number $k$ ($k \neq 1$) is greater than the previous number $k-1$ and the ratio of those two numbers is the same fixed ratio for every $k.$

(Note: In the specific question asked above, $n=1000.$)

In other words, you need to set some fixed ratio $r$ such that $P(2)=r\cdot P(1),$
$P(3)=r^2\cdot P(1),$ $P(4)=r^3\cdot P(1),$ and so forth.

If you do this up to $P(n)=r^{n-1}\cdot P(1)$ and then say $n$ is the largest possible outcome and there are no others, by the law of total probability you must have
\begin{multline}
P(1)+P(2)+P(3)+P(4)+\cdots+P(n)=\\
P(1) + r\cdot P(1)+
r^2\cdot P(1) + r^3\cdot P(1) +
\cdots + r^{n-1}\cdot P(1) = 1.
\end{multline}

This implies that
$$
P(1)=\frac{1}{1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots+ r^{n-1}}
=\frac{r-1}{r^{n}-1}.
$$

So you can set $r$ to any number you like greater than $1$, such as $r=2$ or $r=10$ or even $r=1.005,$
then set $P(1)$ according to the equation above, and then set all the other probabilities as described.

To simulate your distribution in software, a standard method for any probability distribution over the numbers $1$ to $n$ is to compute the cumulative distribution function for every possible outcome. That is, for each possible value $k$, you compute the sum of probabilities 
$P(1)+P(2)+P(3)+P(4)+\cdots+P(k).$
Since you have an exponentially increasing distribution, however, it will often be more accurate to compute $1-P(n)-P(n-1)-\cdots-P(k+1),$
which is the same thing mathematically but reduces some numerical errors in the computer.
In any case the cumulative distribution function is always exactly $1$ at the largest possible random value, $n.$

Continuing the method, you put all the sums of probabilities into an array in increasing sequence.
You then use a pseudorandom function such as `rand()` to generate a pseudorandom floating-point number (not an integer!) in the range $0.0$ to $1.0.$
Next, use binary search to find the smallest number in the array that is still greater than or equal to the output of  `rand()`.
Binary search is recommended because it is generally much faster than looking at each number in sequence within the array. 
Take the position of that number within the array;
in most programming languages this will be an integer from $0$ to $n-1.$
Add $1$ to that integer to get your final “random number” in the range $1$ to $n$.